# How to create a title line in emacs?

Tags: emacs

suppose I have a line:

```
This is a title
```

I want to highlight this line like this:

```
This is a title
===============
```

Any ideas if such functionality is already available in emacs?

Comment: Is this in any particular context; mode, file-type, when, where, etc? Or does this refer to some area of emacs I have not met yet.

Comment: I write plain text files and I want to ascii-highlight the line to make the impression of a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WRT to readability not written the shortest way:

```
(defun underline ()
  (interactive "*")
  (let* ((len (- (line-end-position) (line-beginning-position)))
     (strg (make-string len ?\=)))
    (end-of-line)
    (insert "\n")
    (insert strg)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Heh, I wanted that a long time ago so I wrote one.  I've no idea if it's already packaged and out there in another form.  Here's my version:

```
(defun underline-previous-line ()
  "Insert enough dashes on the current line to \"underline\" the line above the point.
Underline the line above the current point,
but don't underline any whitespace at the beginning of the line.
Delete the current line when made of whitespace and/or dashes."
  (interactive)
  (let ((p (point)))
    (forward-line -1)
    (if (looking-at "^\\([ \t]*\\).+$")
        (progn
          (goto-char p)
          (beginning-of-line)
          (let ((spaces (if (match-end 1) (- (match-end 1) (match-beginning 1)) 0)))
            (insert (concat
                     (make-string spaces ?\ )
                     (make-string (- (match-end 0) (match-beginning 0) spaces) ?\-)
                     (save-match-data
                       (if (looking-at "^[-     ]*-[-   ]*$")  ; need one dash
                           (delete-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
                         "\n")))))))
    (goto-char p)
    ;; yes, next-line is what we want for intuitive cursor placement
    ;; a save-excursion makes life a little more difficult b/c the point
    ;; moves around oldly b/c of the insert
    (next-line 1)))
```

Just change the '-' to '=' and it'll do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Install [markdown-mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/). It does this with the function `markdown-insert-title` (bound to <kbd>C-c C-t t</kbd>).

**Edit**: I don't have the newest version 2.0 yet, but if I understand the release notes correctly, `markdown-insert-title` has been renamed to `markdown-insert-header-setext-1` and its keybinding has been changed to <kbd>C-c C-t !</kbd>.

Comment: nice mode. However, markdown-insert-title only inserts a line with 10 =s, instead of as many as the title has.

Comment: @pyfex: If you have an active region, it will use as many `=`s as you have selected, the fixed length appears only if you use the function without a selection.